# Troubles with crawling an image link

Tags: python, css, image, scrapy, web-crawler

I built a crawler to crawl information on www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de, but besides the given title, price, description and link, I do not get the link of the image of an offered house.

I already tried to use different attributes, like attr(href), attr(src), attr(data-imgsrc)...but nothing seems to work. I only get the div container and I am even not able to split the content of this div container.

import...

[...]

```
start_urls = [
    "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-haus-kaufen/anzeige:angebote/c208"
]

def parse(self, response):

    items = KleinanzeigenItem()

    jede_immobilie = response.css("li.ad-listitem.lazyload-item")

    for immobilie in jede_immobilie:

        title = immobilie.css("a.ellipsis::text").extract()
        preis = immobilie.css("aditem-main, strong::text").extract()
        quadratmeter = immobilie.css(".tag-small:nth-child(1)::text").extract()
        description = immobilie.css(".text-module-begin+ p::text").extract()
        image = immobilie.css("div.srpimagebox, img::attr(src)").extract()
        link_immobilie = immobilie.css("a.ellipsis").xpath("@href").extract()

        items["title"] = title
        items["preis"] = preis
        items["quadratmeter"] = quadratmeter
        items["description"] = description
        items["image"] = image
        items["link_immobilie"] = "https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de"+link_immobilie[0]

        yield items
```

For the variable "image" I expect to get the link for the jpg, but I get the following results:

```
{[...]
 'image': ['<div class="imagebox srpimagebox" '
           'data-href="/s-anzeige/einfamilienhaus-freistehend-in-zentraler-lage/1252437848-208-7416" '
           'data-imgsrc="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/z/CBYAAOSwWI1dyD6R/$_2.JPG" '
           'data-imgsrcretina="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/z/CBYAAOSwWI1dyD6R/$_35.JPG '
           '2x" data-imgtitle="Einfamilienhaus freistehend in zentraler Lage '
           'Bayern - Großostheim Vorschau">\n'
           '                                    </div>'],
 [...]}
```

So I am not sure, how to fix this, because the div-container is too much information for me. And it is so strange, that I can not manipulate this string/list.

E.g. I tried to get element[0] of this list and then I tried to use the split, but it didn't work.

I appreciate your feedback! :)

KR, Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link of the image lies in two attribute of your selected div element. Namely - @data-imgsrcretina and @data-imgsrc. So, Why don't you pick it from there.

For example, following xpath is working for me.

```
>> image = immobilie.css("div.srpimagebox").xpath("@data-imgsrc").extract()
>> image = immobilie.css("div.srpimagebox").xpath("@data-imgsrcretina").extract() 
# take either of the above.
```

Output -

```
>> image
 [u'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/IDUAAOSwimZdcQuw/$_2.JPG']
```